# Ruby/Sinatra send_file not working

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, safari, sinatra, sendfile

I'm using `send_file` on a Sinatra app:

```
get '/update/dl/:upd' do

    filename ="/uploads/#{params[:upd]}"
    send_file(filename, :filename => "t.cer", :type => "application/octet-stream")
end
```

The folder `/uploads/` it's not public, it's on the app dir. When I try to go to `localhost:4567/update/dl/some_file` in Chrome it returns me a 404, like with Firefox, when seeing the headers, it's a 404. But if I try with Safari it downloads the file. So I guess somthing's wrong with my code (and Safari's, but let's left that to Apple :P). What could be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Check that the URL is correct in all browsers. Does the request really reach the sinatra app?

Comment: yeah, Sinatra gets the request, and directly answers it with a 404

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get it to work fine in chrome if I remove the initial slash in filename so it's "filename instead of "/filename. The 404 comes from a file not found error in send_file

```
# foo.rb
require 'sinatra'
get '/update/dl/:upd' do
    filename ="uploads/#{params[:upd]}"
    # just send the file if it's an accepted file
    if filename =~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*.cer$/
      send_file(filename, :filename => "t.cer", :type => "application/octet-stream")
    end
end
```

However, there's really a big security hole in this, a user can download anything that the sinatra process has access too, I named my sinatra app foo.rb and this request downloads the sinatra script:

```
 http://localhost:4567/update/dl/..%2Ffoo.rb
```

Comment: No big deal, only trusted company members will have access

Comment: OK, I added a simple check, it's an unnecessary attack vector to leave open in any case.

Comment: Sinatra by default uses rack-protection with path traversal protection enabled, so this check is unnecessary.

(EDIT: this may not have been true at the time the answer was written but its certainly true now)